# Add letter before space in string

Tags: javascript

I want to add a letter (any letter, lets say p) to the end of every word using regular javascript but im not sure how to do this.
I already have this incomplete code.

```
var y = prompt("type a sentence here!"); //person types in sentence that will get changed//
function funkyfunction() {
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x.charAt(i)==" "){

        }
    }
};
funkyfunction(); //would call the function and print the result
```

Comment: did you mean `var x = prompt(..)`?

Comment: And you are missing a `"`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your problem is? Do have problems identifying a word in a string? Inserting a character into a string? Printing the string? Please be **specific**.

Comment: oops mb meant x and i was having trouble putting the letter into the string after each word

Comment: Do you want to add a p after the last word, which would not be before a space?

Comment: before the space but after the word so for example input is hello everyone then the output would be hellop everyonep

Comment: but now im wondering how would you add a letter to the front of each word in an array instead of the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the last answer the specifics on how to join them together would be something like this

```
var x = prompt("type a sentence here!"); //person types in sentence that will get changed//
function funkyfunction()
{
   var words = x.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        words[i] += "p";
    }
    x = words.join(" ");
    console.log(x); // or alert(x); which ever is most useful
}
funkyfunction(); //would call the function and print the result
```

As you can see we split the string into an array by the delimiter of space to get an array of words, then we loop through the items in the array and just add p to the end of it. at the end we set the original variable equal to the array combined back together with the spaces added back.

Comment: What if there are two spaces in a row?

Comment: if you want to split for one or more spaces use x.split(" +");
Notice I have a space then a plus sign inside there. the plus sign is what is called a regular expression. + means one or more of the previous item which in this case is a space.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), which will split a string on each occurrence of the character you provide it and return an array.

So `"Type a sentence here".split(" ")` would return `["Type", "a", "sentence", "here"]`.

You could then iterate over that array and add a character to the end of each element!

Then use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert the array back into a string. Make sure you pass join the right separator!